# Sound Design Trivia Pop Quiz: In the hit song "Thriller", where did the wolf howling sound effects come from in the beginning?

Tags: sound-effects

The person with the first right answer gets their answer accepted.

Comment: Ryan you're such a joker :D

Comment: @Justin I thought it was a clever way to show there are a myriad of uses your own voice has in sound design. But, apparently someone out there was offended by this. lol...

Comment: haha! Love it... 

Comment: @Andrew Hey, I'm just following the rules of this site and bringing my sense of humor... don't know why I get down-voted for it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man himself, Michael Jackson, performed the wolf howls!

Comment: We have a winner. Let that be a lesson to you all: If you need a wolf howl, you can do it yourself.